# Laravel: passing complex relationships to the view

Tags: laravel

This can be a bit confusing, so please, bear with me

I'm designing an application for an online course.
I have the following tables: users, courses, exercises.

Each course can have many exercises and each user can be enrolled in many courses (there's a course_user table).

There's also a pivot exercise_user table table with a grade column, so I can record user grades on each exercise they do.

So far, so good.

The thing is: at courses's page, I want to display all they exercises in that course,  with the current user's grading in it.

At the Controller, I first check if the user is enrolled in that course ($request->user()->courses->contains($course)) and than pass that course to the view.

After that, I loop through each exercise from that course and display it.

What would be the best method to display users grading in each course?

**EDIT**
Here`s a EER diagram

[image: a diagram]

Answer (score 2):

You could **eager loading** the excersices to you course like this;

```
$course = Course::find($id)->with("excersices")->first();
```

And then in your blade:

```
@foreach($course->excercises as $excercise)
   {{ $excercise->pivot->grade }}
@endforeach
```

More info about [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

**EDIT**

If you make the relation between course and excersice one to many, I think this could work:

```
$course = Course::find($id)->with([//get this course
    'users' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', $request->user()->id); //with only this user
    },'users.excercises' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('course_id', $id); //user excercises for this course
    }
]);
```

And in blade i believe is like this:

```
@foreach($course->users->excercises as $excercise)
   {{ $excercise->pivot->grade }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Simple and smart! Muchas gracias :P

Comment: si sabía hablaba en español XD

Comment: Just occurred  me it's not exactly this :(  That way, I eager load the course_exercise pivot table, but what I need is to eager load the exercise_user table. I guess I could loop through all exercises with that course and than find the user's grading for each of them, but that doesn't sound like the more practical way :(

Comment: I think so. I edited the main post with a EER diagram. Thanks a lot in advance for your time, bro

Comment: its strange that one excercise could belong to more than one course rigth?
i dont know if you can get exactly the data you want, without make some kind of loop at some point.

Comment: Actually not, because the idea is to have multiple courses with the same exercise. BUT if that's the issue, I can change it. It's not 100% required. Would that solve it?